# Track google instant search result for occupation of people using php

Tags: php, curl

[image]

Please check the image, i need to track the occupation of some famous people. I think this instant result from google will be good choice.

This result is populated dynamically from javascript, i used curl and get file contents, but only getting the static html, ie ) not getting the dynamically loading "Andy Warhol Professions" ( The white box contents in the left side ).

How i get the this google instant result using the google search url's like

```
https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Andy+Warhol+occupation
https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Sachin+tendulkar+occupation
https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Barack+obama+occupation
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but should work

```
$page = file_get_contents('https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Andy+Warhol+occupation');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($page);
$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($divs as $div) {
    if ($div->getAttribute('id') === 'rso') {
         echo $div->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: file_get_contents not giving the desired div, which is loading via javascript after page loads. Google maintains all urls as relational urls

thanks for your time and waiting for further reply :)